# Returning a function with the same signature as itself in C#

Tags: c#, types, recursive-datastructures

In my application, I want a function that after doing some work, return a function with the same signature as itself, or null:
Notice that there's nothing generic here, as all type are "static" (as in, the opposite of generic)

```
//type is not a C# keyword, but bear with me
type RecursiveType = Func<int, RecursiveType>;
RecursiveType currentStep; //something not null
var i = 0;
while (currentStep != null) {
    currentStep = currentStep(i);
    i += 1;
}
```

"currentStep" would be something like (this is an example. In the real case Foo::A executes some logic to decide which function it will return, and may or may not be itself)

```
class Foo {
    public static RecursiveType fun(int x) {
        if (x < 3) { 
            return Foo.A
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible in C#?

Comment: You are missing new : return new Foo.A() { set values};

Comment: Foo.A is not a class, it's a function (belonging to the class A), so I can't 'new' it.

Comment: Is there always a single argument of type `int`? Or are the arguments variable?

Comment: Always a single `int` argument.

Comment: Recursive types are not a thing in .NET's type system. The closest you can get is using a type "as itself" in an inheritance or constraint clause (`class C : IEquatable<C>`), but that couldn't be used to emulate this (except very clumsily, with an `IFunc` that has a `Call` method or suchlike). You can achieve this in a non-type safe manner, of course, by using `object` or `dynamic` or something equally non-committal as the return type before casting. You could also wrap this in a class, which is fine with returning itself. You just can't use the generic `Func` to do it.

Comment: What!!!! : class Foo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a delegate type like this:

```
public delegate RecursiveType RecursiveType(int x);
```

Then this will compile:

```
RecursiveType currentStep = Foo.fun(1);
var i = 0;
while (currentStep != null)
{
    currentStep = currentStep(i);
    i += 1;
}
```

The delegate represents a function that accepts an `int` and returns a function of the same signature.

Comment: Clever. I forgot recursive delegate types are a thing. That, combined with method group conversions (and other delegate conversions), allow you to do this more or less directly (`return Foo.fun` inside `Foo.fun` would work).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, or assuming `Foo.A`  also accepts `int` and returns `RecursiveType` as suggested by the OP.